# Hiding some views in the interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xib, nib

Is there a possible way to hide some views in Interface Builder? I don't mean to hide it when the app launches, but to hide it just in Interface Builder to be easy for me to see other views.
Actually I want to do that because my xib file has a lot of views and it is hard to see !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Admdrew,

Unfortunately there is no way you can do that in storyboard. The only thing you can do to view the Views which is overlapped by others, is drag it to the top.

For example, I drag PickerView to the red line to make it to the top, then edit PickerView, and drag it back to the previous position when finish: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e18nmr9mya9y0s8/DizSfOW_3F3a_wV4YVXgFk__h0PoFWbd3rs1HbcTN-4.png

I prefer to use many View Controllers, it's better for your performance. But I must say that in some cases, you still have to use many UIView place on top of others, and I think this is the best way to edit each View.

Cheers,

### **UPDATE AUGUST 17, 2015**

Since XCODE 6.x already added in the feature called "Installed" in the right panel, so now you can easily disable the upper view for temporary by uncheck "Installed", then do-whatever-you-are-planning-to-do with the lower view. Just remember to return it to be checked after you finish.

Step by step following this:
1. Click to select the upper view.
2. On the right panel, look for "Installed".
3. Click to uncheck it.
That's it!

[image: It's at the bottom of this picture]

Cheers!

Comment: Following the Apple tradition of "f**king with things that are well used and working," the Installed option is gone as of Xcode 8.2. Thanks for the courage, Apple.

Comment: On 8.3.3 and this works - they put it back then? Wish I knew about this feature earlier

Comment: Xcode 9.0 they've ref*#ked it again, and removed it.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay I'm using Xcode 9.2 and it's still there, make sure you're at Attributes tab

Comment: Gone in Xcode 13.4

Answer (score 3):

You'd use the **Hidden** property in the Attributes Inspector. But I'm not sure is this is what you'd like to achieve. 
By doing that you'd need to set the attribute to Hidden = NO before running your app.

[image: Hidding Views IB]

I think that using groups of views could be also a better way to handle lot of views in the same xib files. You could do that ***Editor -> Embed In -> View***. Selecting all related views and making groups could help you to work with them easily by hiding or moving some groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually that will not help me, because the interface builder still show the hidden views, Yes when the app launch they area hidden but on the interface builder they are "transparent" and that not so good, I want to hide him not to be transparent !!! :)